# How can I create and manage playlist in phonegap? (audio/Video files)

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to create a playlist in phonegap application for iPhone. I don't have any idea regarding this, I am totally new to this issue, I am not getting any thing, can any one help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: This is not a way of asking any question....u need to discribe each and every step of ur query,one by one and need to tell what u have tried.You have asked your question like you are saying hello to some one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you

[Use PhoneGap Media API & jQuery Mobile UI Framework](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt1part1)

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=screen.width; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Audio Player</title>
    <!-- NOTE: The following 4 lines are inserted by the project wizard -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.css" type="text/css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="page-home">
    <div data-role="header" data-nobackbtn="true" data-theme="e">
    <h1>Audio Player</h1>
    </div> <!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content-manual" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="button" id="playaudio" data-theme="e">Play</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="pauseaudio" data-theme="e">Pause</div>
        <div data-role="button" id="stopaudio" data-theme="e">Stop</div>    

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a"> Current: <span id="audio_position">0 sec</span></div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">Total: <span id=media_dur>0</span> sec</div>
        </div><!-- /grid-a -->

    </div>  <!-- /content-manual -->
</div>  <!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aamir.. Is that above url suite for iOS?

Comment: y not?phonegap has similar syntax for all technology wether it is ios,blackberry,android .....it will surely work if u are using ios with phonegap

Comment: Welcome and remember next time u ask any question than give each and every detail

Comment: Hey Aamir: In that tutorial they are assigning a media file url into a var src, so it can play that media..but how can we manage multiple media files? Is this possible by using an array?

Comment: Is this html5 version support older iOS?